# Questions from the definition phase on Area 51

Tags: discussion

Over on Area 51 you can still browse the list of [example questions](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/63276?phase=definition) that were used in the definition phase before we got to private beta. Some of these have been asked in similar format here, but many have not.

Does it make sense to ask more of the high voted example questions as private beta questions? Should this be done by the original poster or if they have not done so yet can we start to post them ourselves?

Answer (score 7):

I think that any we think are valid questions should be posted, so that the community can judge them by voting and contribute more to defining the scope of the site. Posting an expanded or slightly changed version also contributes to this process - it needn't be word for word.

I don't see any problem with posting a question based on someone else's Area 51 example question. This is a collaborative effort and it helps the site. By all means ask the person concerned if they are around in case they plan to post it themselves, but if they are not I see no reason not to go ahead with posting.

Comment: Now that we're several days in and the original proposers have had a chance, I agree.  Do remember that the Area 51 questions are really just outlines; real questions need to be more developed, which requires work, which may be why they haven't all been asked yet.

Comment: @MonicaCellio this is a good point - they will need to be made complete questions.